# Unable to compare Array element to String using InStr

Tags: vb6

I'm using VB6 and I'm trying to compare a string to an Array element. I know that if the string exists it will always be in index 0. Currently it always skips to `End If`. What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim attributeFinal As String, 
strArray() As String, 
stringFound As Integer, 
code As String

attributes = "Material=10011,C=123123"

strArray = Split(attributes, ",")
If UBound(strArray) Then
    code = strArray(0)
    stringFound = InStr(1, "Material", code)
    If stringFound <> 0 Then
        attributeFinal = code & ",C=" & cCode
    End If
End If
```

Comment: If `UBound(strArray)` is zero then it sees that as `False` and does not execute the body of the If statement. Can you give us sample data?

Comment: It always goes into the `UBound` loop but it never goes into the second loop. I've added some sample data

Comment: From the [documentation for the InStr Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx) it looks like you have the arguments to it the wrong way round, i.e. it shouild be `stringFound = InStr(1, code, "Material")`. And the `1, ` is not needed because you want to start searching from position 1 anyway.

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Comment: There are no loops in this code. I assume you meant conditionals?

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to @AndrewMorton. The arguments for comparing strings were in reverse order.

```
Dim attributeFinal As String, 
strArray() As String, 
stringFound As Integer, 
code As String

attributes = "Material=10011,C=123123"

strArray = Split(attributes, ",")
If UBound(strArray) Then
    code = strArray(0)
    stringFound = InStr(code, "Material")
    If stringFound <> 0 Then
        attributeFinal = code & ",C=" & cCode
    End If
End If
```